Need to install Windows 11 on ThinkCentre M710q with i7-7700T
I have the following results on the PC Health Check:
Processor not currently supported for Windows 11 (Intel Core i7-7700T CPU @ 2.90GHz) With the Following:
This PC supports Secure Boot
TPM enabled on this PC TPM: TPM 2.0
System Memory 16GB
System storage: 500GB SSD
Processor Cores 4


If the processor isn't supported by Windows 11, think the only option is to bypass the check as per the answer

You can use Rufus to create an installer that supports that hardware

That said, why bother? "Microsoft: No... updates for Windows 11 PCs without minimum... requirements", https://www.computerworld.com/article/3623625/no-support-or-updates-for-windows-11-on-machines-not-meeting-minimum-hardware-requirements-says-microsoft.html . It's like pouring kerosene into your cars fuel tank, and waiting to see how long it will keep running.
